# Finding a table using ImportHTML

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

I feel like I've tried every solution out here, and have yet to accomplish this task.

I'm looking to scrape the SECOND (playoffs) table on this link:

https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/curryst01/gamelog/2016

The first table comes in very easily using IMPORTHTML, the second however I haven't been able to locate.

I've tried using IMPORTHTML with 100 different tables & lists.  I also looked in inspector and did a CTRL F on <table and see the info there.

I read that it could be because it's a Javascript object, but when I turned off Javascript (like someone suggested), I still see the table, which leads me to believe it can definitely be scraped into a Google Sheet.

I tried ImportXML as well, but I'm not as familiar and wasn't able to find the info with that either.

Are there any suggestions on how I could scrape this? Seems bizarre to me that it is this difficult!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that IMPORTHTML and IMPORTXML cannot be used for retrieving the table you expect. But, fortunately, I noticed that when the HTML is retrieved by Google Apps Script, the HTML data includes the table of `the SECOND (playoffs) table` you expect. So in this answer, I would like to propose to use Google Apps Script.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet, and [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please run `myFunction` at the script editor. By this, the retrieved table is put to the sheet.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/c/curryst01/gamelog/2016"; // This URL is from your question.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the destination sheet name.

  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const tables = [...html.matchAll(/<table[\s\S\w]+?<\/table>/g)];
  if (tables.length > 8) {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: [{ pasteData: { html: true, data: tables[8][0], coordinate: { sheetId: ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId() } } }] }, ss.getId());
    return;
  }
  throw new Error("Expected table cannot be retrieved.");
}
```

#### Result:

When this script is run, the following result can be obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [PasteDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#pastedatarequest)

Comment: Thanks so much - this is working to pull in the 2nd table.  I'm going to do my best to tweak it so that I can pull both tables at once.  My end goal is to scrape an entire list of URLs to get all of the info.  I'm using ParseHub right now to do so, but if I can alter this a bit it would be easier. Do you have any advice? This is amazing!

Comment: @Anthony Madle Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question of `My end goal is to scrape an entire list of URLs to get all of the info.`, in this case, my proposed script uses `tables[8][0]` for retrieving 2nd table you want to retrieve. So for example, how about modifying `tables[8][0]`? By this, you can retrieve other tables. But I'm not sure about the detail of `My end goal`. So if this was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Hey @Tanaike - I tried to accept your answer by giving it an up arrow but I'm unable to without 15 reputation points.  Is there another way?  Also -- I tried to copy the batchupdate line into two so that I could pull both tables 7 and 8 at once on the same sheet, but it seems that doesn't work.  I can definitely work around it, this is a HUGE help.  Really, I have about 50 links I want to get this info for - I was going to copy and paste the links into this code 50 times, just curious if there is a better way?

Comment: Thank you so much! I just accepted your great solution.  I didn't even realize that checkbox was there.  I will definitely post a new question & explain the things I've tried thus far.  You're amazing!

Comment: Hey @Tanaike - unfortunately I am unable to ask any more questions here.  I added it to WebApps if you are also on that platform.  If not, no worries of course.  I really appreciate all of the help 

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/161952/importhtml-script-at-bulk

Comment: @Anthony Madle Thank you for your response. When I saw your new question, I noticed that your new question had already been resolved. I'm glad for it.

Answer (score 0):

I learned I wasn't turning off Javascript properly... well, now the table is gone.  So I'm assuming this means it cannot be scraped into Sheets.

Still curious what solutions are out there - I'm currently working on it using ParseHub, but I'd really love to understand how it could be done in Sheets

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will give you the main table

```
=importhtml(url,"table",8)
```

you can also retrieve informations for tables #1 to #7

Comment: Thanks Mike - I'm trying to get the Playoffs table though