# Having issue populating table in Sheets using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I found a solution on StackOverflow that I have been using to populate table data from some websites and haven't had any issues with the script (including some modifications I would make depending on the site, etc...) But, I'm having trouble getting the data from this website to populate although I am seeing the response from the `Logger.log(table)`

Is this because `table` is not a valid JSON? Is there any way to modify the script to pull this data?

```
function senate() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const url = 'html';
  const sheetName = "senate"; 
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("senate");
  var lr = dstSheet.getLastRow();
  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const tables = [...html.matchAll(/<table[\s\S\w]+?<\/table>/g)];
  Logger.log(tables)
  if (tables !== null) {
    const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: [{ pasteData: { html: true, data: tables, type: "PASTE_VALUES", coordinate: { sheetId: ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId(),rowIndex: lr, columnIndex: 0 } } }] }, ss.getId());
    return;
  }
  throw new Error("Expected table cannot be retrieved.");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using [this sample script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70477391), I think that in this case, `tables` is an array. So, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: [{ pasteData: { html: true, data: tables, type: "PASTE_VALUES", coordinate: { sheetId: ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId(),rowIndex: lr, columnIndex: 0 } } }] }, ss.getId());
```

#### To:

```
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests: [{ pasteData: { html: true, data: tables[0][0], type: "PASTE_VALUES", coordinate: { sheetId: ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId(),rowIndex: lr, columnIndex: 0 } } }] }, ss.getId());
```

- When I saw `tables.length`, it's 1. So, in this modification, `data: tables` was modified to `data: tables[0][0]`.

Comment: I could have swore I tried the `tables[0][0]` before posting this! Maybe I had some other error in the script and missed it. This solution worked for me, thank you Tanaike! You're always extremely helpful and your scripts are A+ gold standard!

Comment: @LLABS Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.